# Create an Executable from Wordpress

Tags: php, visual-studio, wordpress, executable

I have this huge application that I want to create for an educational company to be running in a connection of schools. It contains more than 1000 revision papers and the same amount of answers. This is about 10000 pages which would be tedious to handle with a desktop programming language such as C or VB.net. After doing some research I found some free PHP to EXE converters. I later thought of designing the application using WordPress(add the questions and answers as posts) but I am not sure how possible this is (factors like Wordpress needs Apache).
I would appreciate your suggestions on how to go about it if it is possible..

Php to EXE converter: http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/

Answer (score 0):

What about using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to run PHP/MySql/Apache, but customizing the installer to install your customized wordpress site and launch the site

Comment: The problem is how to compile it.. that compiler complies only one php file to exe at a time..

Comment: well, my thought when answering was to re-build the installer (if you can directly work with OSS, then you can just recompile the installer) to install the existing WAMP server + your site. There wouldn't be an exe for your app, but you could have a script that starts the server and launches the site